# Finding a unitary matrix and a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am trying to solve this problem but I think I am misunderstanding something. I am given this hermitian matrix A:
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -i\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
i & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
and its eigenvectors, for which I have calculated the corresponding eigenvalues.
\begin{align}
v1&=\begin{bmatrix}
i \\
-1 \\
2\\
\end{bmatrix},
v2&=\begin{bmatrix}
-i \\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix},
v3&=\begin{bmatrix}
i \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix},
v4&=\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
2i \\
-4i
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lambda1&=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 
\end{bmatrix},
\lambda2&=\begin{bmatrix}
1 
\end{bmatrix},
\lambda3&=\begin{bmatrix}
0
\end{bmatrix},
\lambda4&=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
My confusion starts when I have to set up my unitary matrix to satisfy:
\begin{align}
\ D=U^*AU 
\end{align}
Do I just use the 3 eigenvectors with different eigenvalues to set up the unitary matrix? If so, does the multiplicity of the eigenvalue -2 affect the unitary matrix by any way, and also how do you implement the multiplicty in the D matrix? Hope any of you can help me understand it! Thanks :)

Comment: I have been given the 4 eigenvectors for another subquestion of the problem, for which I have just found the eigenvalues. In the pevious subquestion I had to show if those vectors are the matrix' eigenvectors.

Comment: 4 eigenvectors for a 3x3 matrix?  I must be missing something there.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing, but this is what I've got in the problem text from the teacher.

Comment: $v_4 = -2iv_1$, there can only be three eigenvectors at most.

Comment: So v4 is not an eigenvector. In that case should I stick to v1,v2 and v3, and construct my unitary matrix from them? If so, my confuse regarding the multiplicity does not apply.